# BEGINNER JavaScript creating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on creating elements via Java Script. For practice I am trying to populate an already existing 'form' element with a button, however I am receiving the following error;

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <form></form>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var txt = document.createTextNode('CLICK ME');
    btn.appendChild(txt);

    document.getElementById('#form').appendChild(btn);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: No need for a `#` in `getElementById`. JavaScript already knows you're giving it an ID, you don't have to tell it so ;)

Comment: getElementById works on the "id attribute". See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not assign your `<form>` element an ID of `form`.

```
<body>  
    <form id="form">

    </form>
</body>
```

You also don't need a `#` when using `getElementById()`.

```
document.getElementById('form').appendChild(btn);
```

If you don't want to assign an ID, you can use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: Also the script needed to be in either a ready() or after the elements have been declared. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't think a singular version exists.

Comment: You're right. I had a brainfart. I meant `querySelector` as the singular form of `querySelectorAll`. `getElementsByTagName` indeed doesn't have a singular form.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form id="f">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
            var txt = document.createTextNode('CLICK ME');
            btn.appendChild(txt);
            document.getElementById("f").appendChild(btn);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

- `<script>` should either be inside the `<head>` or `<body>`.
- You didn't set an id for `<form>`. Otherwise you can use
  `getElementsByTagName()`.

Ex:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.`<script>` cannot be outside outside of `<body>`

2. You've not given your form an `id`.
3. AND you don't need `#` because it's CSS syntax for ids and the method already knows you are providing it an id.